# Using superclass type to filter templates removes modifications to static variable in superclass

Tags: java, templates, generics, inheritance, static

In order to explain I'll use an example

```
//Superclass.java
public class Superclass
{
    static String TypeInfo = "Superclass";
}
```

---

```
//Subclass.java
public class Subclass extends Superclass
{
    static {
        TypeInfo = "Subclass";
    }
}
```

---

```
//Main.java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(GetTypeInfo(Subclass.class));
    }
    public static <T extends Superclass> String GetTypeInfo(Class<T> c)
    {
        return T.TypeInfo;
    }
}
```

---

When the class is templatized all information from the classloader seems to be lost, or the jvm takes the initial value of superclass over subclass, why dose all information statically initialized by subclass become hidden when it is templatized?

Comment: There is no such thing like “templatized” in Java. `GetTypeInfo` will always perform the same action regardless of the Generic type arguments, i.e. read the same `static` field in your case. Since you have only one field in your code, it is only good for detecting whether the initializer of `Subclass` which overwrites that field has been executed. [fabian explained why it hasn’t](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26074392/2711488)

Answer (score 1):

`Subclass` ins never initiallized and therefore the static block never runs.

According to [JLS 12.4.1. "When Initialization Occurs "](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) a class is only initialized in the following cases:

- a instance of the class is created
- a static method declared in the class is invoked
- a static non-constant field declared in the class is accessed
- the class is a top level class, and an assert statement lexically nested within the class is executed

If a field is accessed through an subclass of the class where it is declared, it has the same effect as if it was invoked using the class where it is declared.

Using reflection may also cause initialisation.

None of these conditions are met for `Subclass`, therefore the static block is never executed.

---

If `Subclass` is initialized, you get the expected result, e.g. if you use this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Subclass();
    System.out.print(GetTypeInfo(Subclass.class));
}
```